# What is the type of `function` and of `module`

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> type(OptimizedRectangle) 
    <class 'type'>    
>>> type(OptimizedRectangle.get_area)
<class 'function'>
```

So a method of a class is an instance of class `function`.

```
>>> type(function)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

Since `function` is a class and a class is an object, what is the type of `function`, i.e. what is it an instance of?

As the comments suggested

```
>>> type(type(OptimizedRectangle.get_area))
<class 'type'>
```

Then why does `type(function)` not work? Is `function` a class, of which a class's method is an instance?

---

Similarly, why does `type(module)` not work?

```
>>> type(builtins)
<class 'module'>
>>> type(module)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'module' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you try `type(type(OptimizedRectangle.get_area))` ?

Comment: That should be obvious. `type(...)` returns a type. So `type(type(...))` will be `type`.

Comment: FunctionType:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.FunctionType
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/types.html#types.FunctionType

Comment: `function` and `module` are instances of `type`. You get `NameError`s because `function` and `module` aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: @Jim how can an undefined instance of `type` be the type of an existing object?

Comment: I've lost you here, Tim. Did you take a look at the article I posted in the other question you made?

Comment: The fact that the class is named `function` or `module` doesn't mean it's actually available through name lookup for the name `function` or `module`. Those are two different kinds of names, only linked by convention and by the default behavior of the `class` statement.

Comment: In other words, you are conflating `some_object.__name__` with a variable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could you specifically point out what I conflated?

Comment: `function` the variable isn't defined. But the *function type is defined*. It just isn't assigned to the name `function` in any of the namespaces you have access to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in module [`types`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html) stores all kind of different types that are used throughout the language. It contains also the [`FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType) which corresponds to the instance method:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def bar(self):
...         pass
>>> type(Foo.bar) is types.FunctionType
True
```

When calling `type(Foo.bar)` in the interpreter then the output is `<class 'function'>` however this does not necessarily mean that the class's name is `'function'` but it is just the class's representation (`__repr__`):

```
>>> type(types.FunctionType).__repr__(type(Foo.bar))
"<class 'function'>"
```

As pointed out in the comments `types.FunctionType` also only holds a reference to the type of functions which is defined at the implementation level.

The type of `FunctionType` is `type` again, that is `FunctionType` is an instance of `type` (as it is the case for all classes).

Also note the peculiarity

```
>>> type(type) is type
True
```

which means that type is its own class (i.e. `type.__class__` pointing to itself). This is achieved at the implementation level.

Comment: Be aware that the `types` module isn't special. It's not where any of the `types.Whatever` types are implemented, and the names defined there aren't the "real" names or anything. For example, to define `types.FunctionType`, `types.py` just defines a function `_f` and sets `FunctionType = type(_f)`.

Comment: Thanks. "The built-in module types stores all kind of different types that are used throughout the language. " Since the types defined in the module `types` are used throughout the language, why are they not defined as builtin types (like `list`, `int`) in the language, but in module `types` in the standard library?

Comment: @Tim All objects that you can use in Python without additional imports are stored in the module `__builtins__`. Those objects build the "basis" of the language and are likely to be used often (for example conversions to `int` or `list`). For the definition of a function however there is the `def` statement, i.e. no need to refer to the specific type. Also with duck typing users will likely test for `callable(...)` rather than compare to `FunctionType`. The objects stored in `types` rather provide a standard for comparing the specific types of certain objects (whenever that is required).

Comment: Thanks. @a_guest. "All objects that you can use in Python without additional imports are stored in the module `__builtins__`". Do you mean that in Python 3, all builtin types such as `int` and `dict` are  imported from module `builtins`? Aren't they built-ins of the language, instead of a module?

Comment: @Tim To be precise the name of the module is [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) but it is made available by binding it to the name `__builtins__` (at least for CPython). The built-in types are implemented in the language of the interpreter (C for CPython for example) and are made available through this `builtins` module. This makes the language more self-contained because those built-ins can be treated just as regular Python objects (the same way as user-defined objects). Otherwise this information about built-ins would have to be stored in the compiler somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

A function is the simplest callable object in Python.
[read more here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Functions)